# How can I analyse repeated cross-sectional data where some respondents occur in multiple cross-sections?

Tags: longitudinal-data-analysis

I'm working on a project with a polling company. I have access to some of the micro-data from their voting intention polls. I'd like to link these to GDP figures to test how economic change affects individuals' voting intention.

Ideally, I'd treat each poll as a cross-section. But, as these are internet surveys, some respondents participate in multiple surveys. As such, their errors are likely to be correlated. Were this panel data, I'd use something like a multilevel model for change, but I'm not sure if that is appropriate where most of the respondents were surveyed on only a single occasion.

Does anyone have any advice on an alternate way to model the data that accounts for this?

Answer (score 0):

In Longitudinal study or panel data collecting, the researchers follow the same group of subject to measure the response variable repeatedly. This action is on purpose and follows the study plan. Under this situation, the correlation between the measurements from the same subject is not ignorable, and must incorporate the correlation into the model by using random effect.

Your situation is different. Your repeated measurements happened by chance, in addition most of the respondents were surveyed on only a single occasion, so you do not need to worry about correlation due to repeated measurements, and analyze the data as sectional survey data.

Comment: This may be a place for random effects.  See also [this](https://fharrell.com/post/re).

Comment: A simple solution is to use the robust cluster sandwich covariance estimator.

Answer (score 0):

In your situation I recommend just using cluster robust standard errors to account for the fact that errors are correlated for observations associated with the same individual. A multilevel model would be more applicable if most observations were included multiple times.